# Implementation of prefix-span algorithm

Tags: algorithms

This is a very elegant [implementation](https://github.com/chuanconggao/PrefixSpan-py/commit/441b04eca2174b3c92f6b6b2f50a30f1ffe4968c) of prefix-span algorithm by the maintainer of the prefixspan pip package. However, I am having a hard time understanding the reason behind the implementation. The result by `localOccurs` doesn't really make any sense to me. Can I get a overview of what each part of this implementation achieve? particularly what `mine_rec` and `localOccurs` do. Thanks!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from collections import defaultdict

db = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [7, 6, 5, 3, 4],
]

minsup = 2

results = []


def mine_rec(patt, mdb):
    def localOccurs(mdb):
        occurs = defaultdict(list)

        for (i, stoppos) in mdb:
            seq = db[i]
            for j in range(stoppos, len(seq)):
                l = occurs[seq[j]]
                if len(l) == 0 or l[-1][0] != i:
                    l.append((i, j + 1))

        return occurs

    for (c, newmdb) in localOccurs(mdb).items():
        newsup = len(newmdb)

        if newsup >= minsup:
            newpatt = patt + [c]

            results.append((newpatt, [i for (i, stoppos) in newmdb]))
            mine_rec(newpatt, newmdb)


mine_rec([], [(i, 0) for i in range(len(db))])

print(results)
```

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here, so I'm not sure that a question asking us to explain code is within the scope of our site.  Any community votes?

Comment: @D.W., I would say it’s ok as long as it’s rewritten as pseudocode, some basic information about prefixspan algorithm is included and it’s explained why the result is unexpected. I mean, they don’t ask us to code/debug anything.

Comment: (The code presented is far from following the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction) in documentation, commenting and naming.)

Comment: (@D.W. I'd think it OK where the procedure is crystal clear and what asks for explication is why it does solve the problem.)

Comment: Please name the author of the code. Consider nesting the code block in a block comment.

Comment: What is this procedure supposed to do?